# Ajax is not sending input of type password

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with **AJAX** , not sending the input of type password and when i change type to **TEXT**
it sends the data normally , the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  
   
</head>

<body>
        <input type="text" id="username">
        <input type="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" id="subit" value="send">
        <div id="par"></div>
        <script>
            var user = $("#username").val();
            var pass = $('#password').val();
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#subit").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url: "home.php",
                  data:{subit:1, username: user, password: pass }
                }).done(function(resdata){
                   $("#par").html(resdata);
                });
              });  

            });
       </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

and code for processing data

```
<?php

require_once 'queries.php';
if(isset($_POST['subit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$data = selectrow("users","username,password","'$username','$password'");
if(!empty($data)){
    echo $data['username']." ".$data['password'];
} else {
    echo "No Data Found";
}
```

}

?>

i am connecting to the database and checking the data if exist , the **PHP** code is not wrong as i tried it with form and it was working ,now i am using **AJAX**, and not working now saying that **data is not found** , the second echo.

Comment: I know this is a little off-topic, but it looks awfully like you are storing passwords in plain text in your database, which you really don't want to do. I don't know what your `selectrow()` function does, maybe it handles the `password_verify()` side of things.

Comment: Don't you need to assign values to `user` and `pass` in the button-click function? You don't seem to do that.

Comment: @droopsnoot i know that is awful to store password in plain text , this code is for testing ,not a real project and thanks for the advice

Comment: @droopsnoot it seems like that worked thx , i think it was a lack of concentration , thanks for helping me